# Benchmarking with Siege always returns zero hits and zero failed transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, proxy, load-testing, siege

All,

I'm learning to do benchmark testing using the [Siege tool](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) against our Rails app. I'm running Siege on my OS X box against a website hosted on another server. When I run it I always get zero hits and zero failed transactions no matter which site I run it against.

Because of the limitations of OS X, I've configured more ports with `sudo sysctl -w net.inet.tcp.msl=1000` and more open files with `launchctl limit maxfiles 10000 10000`. I've also configured proxy variables in **.siegerc** since I'm running behind a proxy. Sample command line is:
`siege -c1 -b -t10S 'www.google.com'`.

But no matter which website I hit, I always get zero hits, zero failures and zero successful transactions. The Siege log file does not show any errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
siege -c1 -b -t10S 'www.google.com'
** SIEGE 3.0.5
** Preparing 1 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...

Lifting the server siege...      done.

Transactions:                  0 hits
Availability:               0.00 %
Elapsed time:               9.84 secs
Data transferred:           0.00 MB
Response time:              0.00 secs
Transaction rate:           0.00 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:                0.00
Successful transactions:           0
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            0.00
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

Comment: I figured it out. I didn't have the proxy configured properly. I expected to see an error that would guide me, but no error. The following two items need to be set in ~/.siegerc:
proxy-host
proxy-port